# Database Client Design to support different backends

Tags: java, database, design-patterns

What are usable **design patterns** to use for implementing a data base client capable of supporting various backends? (e.g. mongodb, or postgres,...)

As a very simple approach, I would simply create an interface which defines methods for all the CRUD operations:

```
interface DBDriver {
  void write(String data);
  String read();
  ...
}
```

Classes implementing this interface would then be injected in a `Client` class like:

```
class DBClient() {
  public DBClient(DBDriver dbDriver) {
    ...
  }

  //methods like write, read, update ...

}
```

Comment: DAO pattern will help you in this situation!

Comment: Read this question, it might guide you http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36519/generic-dao-written-in-java?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to encapsulate database specific details while exposing a common interface.

[Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to instantiate the correct adapter.

The DAO pattern is essentially an adapter.